# How to run Checkstyle code analysis from Intellij IDEA "Run/Debug Configuration"

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have a configuration in "Run/Debug Configuration" (Run->Edit Configurations) that runs some tests. I would like this configuration to run also Checkstyle check before tests.

How to do it? Is it possible?

I have CheckStyle-IDEA plugin installed (version 5.15.0). Usually I run it manually using
`Analyze->Run Inspection by name->"Checkstyle real-time scan".`
Checkstyle is also run in some of my maven tasks that builds app. However I want to run it also as "Run/Debug Configuration" with tests as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run one configuration before the other configuration.

1. Create the first configuration to run Maven Checkstyle plugin using
   `Edit Configuration -> Maven`
2. Create second JUnit configuration and choose the previous configuration in the field under **Before launch**
   I have added a picture to help you.

[image]